# How to Include all Sub-directories in a Command

Tags: bash, shell, processing, bin, ubuntu-server

I have been working on a script that allows me to take .pde files (processing files), in a said directory, and convert them to an .html file so that they can be viewed on the web. My script works great, however, it only works for one user (/default/files/users/user1). I am wondering how I change the script so it looks for all .pde files in all users (not just /user1, but /user2, /user3, etc.) I am hoping I will not have to just copy the script, manually changing the directory for each user. Here is my code:

```
!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/sites/default/files/users/user1

for f in *.pde

do

            echo > /var/www/sites/default/files/users/user1/${f%.pde}.html

            echo "<script src='processing-1.4.1.min.js'></script>" >> ${f%.pde}.html

            echo "<canvas data-processing-sources='${f%.pde}.pde'></canvas>" >> ${f%.pde}.html

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up, then down:

```
for f in ../user*/*.pde
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but one more thing...how would that affect my other 3 lines? would I have to do something like: /users/${userf%}/ (for line 1) and then specify said user for the last two echo lines?